# Trying to find the same item in a list with the context of hangman

Tags: python, list, python-3.4

I am doing a hangman project in python, and am having a bit of trouble. When a letter in the word is repeated (eg. 'n' in 'banana') I want my code to output:

```
>>>_ _ N _ N _
```

instead of

```
>>>_ _ N _ _ _
```

as it does currently. Here is my code:

```
def click_1 (key):
    if key in word:
        x = word.index(key)
        for key in word[x]:
            hidden_word[x] = key
            print (hidden_word)
    else:
        print ("Nope")
```

where:

```
word = word_list[random.randint(0,3)]
```

and:

```
hidden_word = ["_ "] * len(word)
```

If someone could provide help for this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Why am I getting down voted? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str.index()` only ever returns the *first match* in a string. Rather than finding each matching word, loop over all characters in `word` with an index provided by the [`enumerate()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
def click_1 (key):
    if key in word:
        for index, character in enumerate(word):
            if character == key:
                hidden_word[index] = character
        print (hidden_word)
    else:
        print ("Nope")
```

Quick demo:

```
>>> word = 'BANANA'
>>> hidden_word = ["_ "] * len(word)
>>> def click_1 (key):
...     if key in word:
...         for index, character in enumerate(word):
...             if character == key:
...                 hidden_word[index] = character
...         print (hidden_word)
...     else:
...         print ("Nope")
... 
>>> click_1('N')
['_ ', '_ ', 'N', '_ ', 'N', '_ ']
>>> click_1('B')
['B', '_ ', 'N', '_ ', 'N', '_ ']
>>> click_1('A')
['B', 'A', 'N', 'A', 'N', 'A']
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, fixed the problem very simply and understandably. So enumerate is basically the same as index, except it doesn't only return one number?

Comment: @18166: `enumerate()` simply adds a running index to a sequence. So `character` is bound to each character in `word`, and `enumerate()` adds a counter with that.

Comment: There's a much easier way of handling this. Rather than trying to keep track of your "hidden word," just generate it on the fly each time. Your hidden word should always be `''.join([letter if letter in guessed_letters else "_" for ch in real_word])`. Since in a standard hangman game you should be saving the guessed letters anyway, this is a simple way to handle that.

Comment: @adamsmith I like what you have put, but what is ch and real_world?

Comment: @18166 whoops, `ch` was left over from a re-factor that was supposed to make it easier to understand, but that just made it harder :). `real_word` is the opposite of `hidden_word` -- it's the actual unmasked word. So it would be something like `''.join([letter if letter in guessed_letters else "_" for letter in word])`

Comment: @AdamSmith Haha,  I read it as real_worLd xD Yeah thanks for your comment :)

Comment: @AdamSmith, took your advice, my code runs well now with your suggestions, however i'm now trying to update my label on my gui to match the progression of the game, but using textvariable doesn't work, and just using text = doesn't update the label. Any insight?

Comment: @18166 that sounds like a separate question! Write something up and you'll probably get a number of responses, because there are a lot of people out there who are way better with tkinter than I am :)

Comment: @AdamSmith I got it to work, but the code you suggested to me does not keep the list, and overwrites it each time a button is pressed so that _ A _ _ becomes _ _ E _ when E is pressed. Any insight?

Comment: @18166 sounds like you're not saving a list of previous guesses anywhere! You should have a `set` somewhere that has all the letters the player has guessed.

Comment: @AdamSmith I am not familiar with 
    set
and I have looked up on the internet and don't see how it might be useful of fit into my code. Sorry for taking your time, but if I learn it now, it'll help me in future programming and then I wont have to ask as much.